# Perforce group privileges

Tags: perforce

How can I check via `p4` or `p4v` what privileges / assets does a certain group grant to its users?

I checked the documentation and couldn't find anything close to my issue so correct me if I'm wrong - I see that adding a user to a group allows him to view some directory (which was previously secured via `p4 protect`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do:

```
p4 protects -g GROUP
```

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/cmdref/p4_protects.html

Note that this shows you the permissions that would be applied to someone who is ONLY in that group -- a user who is a member of multiple groups will have additional permissions applied, which may be either additive or subtractive.  Permissions may also be applied per-user, which again may override or add to the permissions granted via groups.  To see the permissions for a particular user:

```
p4 protects -u USER
```

Answer (score 0):

`p4 group <group name>` will give you a lot of info about the group.

`p4 protect` will show you what permissions they have.

From P4V, *Tools-->Administration* will give you an overall view, too.